# PIVOT row values into rows and columns side by side dynamically and concatenate 2 values separated by comma in a cell

Tags: sql, pivot

I need to display my row values into rows and columns side by side dynamically and concatenate 2 values separated by comma in a cell. See example below. Any helps is appreciated.

```
Table1

Toys  CostPrice    SellingPrice
----  ---------    -------------
A      10.55       12.60
B      7.60        8.90
C      8.90        10.50
D      11.50       13.40
E      17.50       20.30
F      2.57        3.50
```

I need to display in this format. Thanks.

```
Toys    A             B           C            D           E         F  
----  -----         -------      ----         ---         ----      ---
A     10.55,12.60
B                 7.60,8.90
C                             8.90,10.50
D                                         11.50,13.40
E                                                      17.50,20.30
F                                                                   2.57,3.50
```

Comment: Not the simplest in SQL...SQL is your data retrieval layer, not so much your display layer.  Easiest way to do this is to export your results to excel and let it pivot it.  If you want a pure SQL answer, this question comes up about 10 times daily on here....search the site for an answer.

Comment: Which dbms????????

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, once more then! First, you'll notice I made a Temp Table instead of a table variable for the example, the @tablecolumns variable required that. Doesn't really apply to you but it was a change I made to be aware of if you copy/paste the code to play with it.

@tablecolumns is the dynamic piece you need, it creates a value that ends up looking like this "[A], [B], [C]...." for the pivot table.

Now you'll need to run the query as Dynamic SQL to toss in your @tablecolumns variable correctly. (Depending on how intensive your actual query gets you may decide to  put the Query itself in a view and select/concatenate what you need from the view instead, I find Dynamic SQL a bit odd so sometimes that's easier)

```
create table #toystab (Toys nvarchar(1), Cost decimal (5,2), Sell decimal (5,2))

insert into #toystab values ('A', 5.50, 6.60)
insert into  #toystab values ('B', 6.50, 7.60)
insert into  #toystab values ('C', 7.50, 8.60)
insert into  #toystab values ('D', 8.50, 9.60)
insert into  #toystab values ('E', 11.50, 12.60)
insert into  #toystab values ('F', 13.50, 14.60)

DECLARE @tablecolumns nvarchar(max)
select @tablecolumns = (COALESCE( @tablecolumns +',', '')
                      + '[' + convert(nvarchar(10), #Toystab.Toys) +']')
from #toystab


declare @Query nvarchar(max)
set @Query = '
select *
from (
select Toys Toy1, Toys ToyName,
CONCAT(cast(Cost as varchar(10)), '','', cast(Sell as varchar(10))) as [ConcatenatedPrice]
 from #toystab) Toyz

pivot
(
MAX(ConcatenatedPrice)
for Toy1 in (' + @tablecolumns+ ')
)
as [Pivot]
'
exec(@Query)

drop table #toystab
```

Notice a couple things. First its that I'm selecting the Toys column twice, once to pivot and once to be a column still. Second, in the CONCAT statement the separator '','' is not a quote (") it is two apostrophes (''). If you make it a quote "," then you'll get an Invalid column error. Last as a reminder, make sure Exec (@query) includes the parens.

Comment: Could be cleaned up with some ISNULLs to make the NULL answers blank.

Comment: Thanks you Bwoods. Your format is what I wanted but I need to make the Toy names dynamically in columns across and rows top down  because I do not know how many Toy names I have each time. It can be from A to F the first month and next month it can be A to Z. Also, the toy names changes it might not always be  in Alphabet. I used A to F just for example the real names are different. Let me know if there is a way to do it dynamically. Thanks.

Comment: Since you updated the question... I did something similar recently. I'll update my answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Thank you Bwoods. It works and I only need to add group by for duplicate toy name on my query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you Bwoods. Your format is what I wanted but I need to make the Toy names dynamically in columns across and rows top down because I do not know how many Toy names I have each time. It can be from A to F the first month and next month it can be A to Z. Also, the toy names changes it might not always be in Alphabet. I used A to F just for example the real names are different. Let me know if there is a way to do it dynamically. Thanks.